# Optimise ASP.NET CMS KooBoo for good SEO

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kooboo

I am considering using KooBoo CMS ASP / MVC CMS for a client.

One of their requirements is good SEO optimisation. What is the best way to do this in KooBoo. How does it compare to, say, Orchard CMS in this area? (and Wordpress, say).

I am talking about things like keywording, friendly URL's & generally behaving in a way Google likes and rewards in search results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the meta tags and description for each pages in KooBoo. Please following the step which is mentioned in kooboo help.

http://www.kooboo.com/docs/Kooboo-CMS/Page-settings

Please also see below link for URL rewriting of different site.

http://www.kooboo.com/docs/Kooboo-CMS/Kooboo-multi-sites-solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe that extra support options were added for V4 of Kooboo.  You now have a number of options.

Each Kooboo 'Site' has a 'System / Settings' page with a 'HTML Meta' section on it.  This allows you to define site-wide meta tag values for all the common meta tags, as well as defining some of your own custom tags.

[image: Site-level meta tag settings]

The same level of detail can be achieved on a page-level basis, where these values will be prefixed to the site-level values, allowing you to have titles like:  -

You can also use tokens in the settings, that will get replaced with context-relevant values:

[image: Page-level meta tag settings]

You also have a very high level of control over the URL's that Kooboo allows access to.  Its default approach is for each piece of content to generate a SEO friendly "user key" that can be used to refer to the content.  This User Key can then be used as part of the URL to access the page.

[image: Example of SEO friendly URL in Kooboo]

There is also native support for 'Robots.txt' and whilst generating a 'SiteMap.xml' is a little more hands-on, it offers perfect granular control for the developer: http://kooboo-cms.ru/articles/detail/sitemap-for-kooboo-cms/

I'm not yet familiar enough with Orchard to say if it offers the same level of SEO targetting, but I think Kooboo has all the major options nicely covered.